# Chinese text incorrectly identified as Portuguese

Tags: ibm-watson

When I pass a snippet of Chinese text to the IBM Watson language detection method, the text is incorrectly identified as `pt` -- Portuguese:

```
curl -X POST -d "outputMode=json" \ 
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translation/api/v2/identify" \
--data-urlencode "text=中国的工厂" \
--header "content-type: text/plain" \
--user "MY_USERNAME:MY_PASSWORD"
```

Am I encoding the text wrong, or doing something else wrong?

Or are IBM Watson's language identification models not useful in some cases, with Portuguese being returned as some kind of default?

Comment: Did you try appending "; charset=UTF-8" to the content-type header?

Comment: What is the output of `env | grep -e LC_ -e LANG` ?

Comment: Strange.  If you try it with a browser, what is the output?

Comment: But "ja" is japanese.  Isn't it?

Comment: Use the debug and verbose options of curl.  Also try using the header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" and with --data instead of --data-urlencode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to the old deprecated service. I am actually surprised that you got any result. The API for the current service record that you should be using is documented here - https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/language-translator/api/v2/?curl#identify

The sample curl command is:

```
curl -u "{username}":"{password}" \
-H "content-type: text/plain" \
-H "accept: application/json" \
-X POST \
-d "this is a test" \
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api/v2/identify"
```

Comment: I had overlooked that the the new version uses `language-translator` instead of `language-translation` in the URL. Thank you!